# How to align all elements in body to right

Tags: css

I have nested body structure like below

```
 <body>
     <div style="position:absolute"> 
      <div>Some Content </div> <img src="abc.png"></div>
      <div> Some other content </div>
      ...
      ...
     </div>
 </body>
```

How can I align elements inside the body to right/center/left?

Comment: Are you talking about aligning the div immeditately in the body, or everything inside that div, or both?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you mean but, you can "align left" by using CSS property `float:left` likewise `float:right` to "align right".

To center a div set the `width` and use `margin:auto`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an open question as it depends on what you are trying to achieve but one of the following may help you:

If your div is positioned absolutely then you can use:

```
position:absolute; right:0px;
```

Or you could use a float, if appropriate:

```
float:right;
```

Or you can use margins to position in the centre, as long as your div has a width specified and NO float:

```
width:100px; margin:0px auto;
```